# Send POST request and get items in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im writing my first app with Angular and now faced up with the problem... I have address for POST request with authentication token. Something like:

```
http://example.com/orders?authentication_token=123456
```

So I need to make `ng-submit` or `ng-click` that send that request and get a bunch of items and show them on the page...
Also, I have a `body` for them:

```
{
"order": {
    "seller_id":84,
    "price":123,
    "delivary_date":"12-12-2025",
    }
}
```

So, what the best way to do that?

Comment: So what is the problem? Documentation has perfect examples of how to use $http service.

Comment: Question is really far too broad. Suggest you narrow this down to bite size chunks and look for tutorials and read docs for the more specific issues first. This site isn't a tutorial or code writing service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you will have to make one angular service which would communicate with server and fetch the data and one angular controller which will interact with service to get the data and display over the UI.

### Lets say service name is MyService:

```
app.service('MyService', function($http) {
    var params = {}; // some parameters
    this.getData = function(successCallback, failureCallback) {
        $http.post("URL", params).then(function(data) {
            successCallback(data);
        }, function(data, status) {
            failureCallback(data, status);
        });
    }
});
```

### Controller name is MyCntrl:

```
app.controller('MyCntrl', function($scope, MyService) {

    function successCallback(data) {
        $scope.itemList = data;  
    }

    function failureCallback(data, status) {
        $scope.itemList = {};
    }

    $scope.handleClick = function() {
        MyService.getData(successCallback, failureCallback);
    }
});
```

I believe it would help you to resolve your requirement!!!

Comment: Thank you so much!) I re-wrote it a bit: `app.controller('MyCntrl', ['$scope', 'MyService', function($scope, MyService) {...}]);`

Comment: Yes thats gr8 this would help you to not break your code when you try to minified the code!!!

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a `orderCtrl`. `ng-click` or `ng-submit` is based on your app requirement. Call the function  `someFunction()` that triggers `$http` post and you can handle the success and failure response.

```
app.controller('orderCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.someFunction = function(){
  var data = {}; // prepare your data here. 
  $http({
    method : "POST",
    url : "specify your url here",
    data : data
  }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      var response = response.data;
       // handle your success here
    }, function myError(response) {
      // handle the failure here
  });

 });
});
```

**Note :**

If you are using a form and you want to trigger this function after user filling all the information, then use `ng-submit`. If it is independent then use `ng-click`.

I'm saying again, it's all depends on what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you) I think I need to write the staff correct from the beginning of my learning AJS, so I prefer to keep services and controllers separate from each other)